# In python, how to restore the function of os.chdir() if os.chdir = 'path' has been implemented

Tags: python

In path setup, I wrongly wrote the code: os.chdir = '\some path', which turns the function os.chdir() into a string. Is there any quick way to restore the function without restarting the software? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps try [reloading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/437591/353839) the `os` module?

Answer (score 8):

Kicking `os` out of the modules cache can make it freshly importable again:

```
>>> import sys, os
>>> os.chdir = "d'oh!"
>>> os.chdir()
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
>>> del sys.modules['os']
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir
<function posix.chdir>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import os
```

Assign to the `chdir` method a string value:

```
>>> os.chdir = '\some path'
>>> os.chdir
'\some path'
```

Use `reload` to, well, reload the module. `reload` will reload a *previously imported* module.

```
>>> reload(os)
>>> os.chdir
<built-in function chdir>
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: This will work as-is in Python 2, but in Python 3 onwards, `reload` needs to be imported differently. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/437591/8305056) for how to import `reload` depending on your version of Python.